# Raw data parsing

Tags: java

I have a byte array with length is 18 with the following structure:

```
unsigned int a;
unsigned int b;
unsigned short c;
unsigned long d;
```

I know that I don't have unsigned * data type in Java. After searching form web, I find that I should use a bigger data type to store the value. For example, I should use int to store an unsigned short variable.

I have two questions. The first one is how to parsing the byte array to get the value from the array to the variable I am using. The second one is how to handle unsigned long variable? I know that may be `BigInteger` can help me but I am not sure how to work it out.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what it is you're accomplishing.  You have a `byte[]` of data (likely from a stream), and you're attempting to read them into different variables, right?

Comment: Whether or not you need to simulate unsigned depends on what you're doing with it.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, your are right.

Comment: Do you have access to the raw stream, or buffer instance, or is all you have a `byte[]`?

Comment: @Makoto Basically, I have a DatagramPacket, and I convert it to a byte[]. which one is easier to handle?

Comment: The answer below seems to offer a good solution.  I'd recommend the use of a ByteBuffer to at least abstract away the bit fiddling you'd need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two practical ways to decode the data. Either you could do the byte-fiddling manually like this (assuming little-endian):

```
a = (array[0] & 0xff) | ((array[1] & 0xff) << 8) | ((array[2] & 0xff) << 16) | ((array[3] & 0xff) << 24);
// Analogously for the others
// The "& 0xff"s are for stripping sign-extended bits.
```

Alternatively, you can use a `java.nio.ByteBuffer`:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
a = buf.getInt();
// Analogously for the others
```

There are, of course, an infinitude of ways to go about it; these were just examples. Initializing a `DataInputStream` from a `ByteArrayInputStream` could be another example.

As for handling `unsigned long`s, Java obviously can't do it generally, but depending on what kind of operations you intend to carry out on them, you may not have to care. General bit-fiddling like ANDs, ORs and bit-shifting generally,  and also simple arithmetic like addition and subtraction, don't care about signedness, after all (though do check out the differences between `>>` and `>>>`).

If you really want to do general `unsigned long` arithmetic, then indeed `BigInteger`s are probably your only (practical) way.

Comment: I was thinking that a `ByteBuffer` would probably be the cleanest way to go here.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just wanted to show the "primitive" way to go about it.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Sorry, I don't understand the meaning of "& 0xff", My understanding is that array[0] & 0xff is equal to 8 bit xxxx xxxx and 1111 1111, so the result is always xxxx xxxx, which is always same to the input 8 bits.

Comment: @sflee: The problem is that Java, as you rightly point out, only uses signed values, so as the `byte` values are promoted to `int`s for shifting, they are sign-extended, so your simple `0xff` extends to `0xffffffff`.